# Remove repeating elements in ArrayList between first and last occurrence to optimise a path

Tags: java, optimization, arraylist

This is for a robotics project. I have used A* to find the path between two coordinates but I want to optimize this further so that the movement of the robot is smoother. I can't quite seem to find a solution that meets my needs so far.

I am also using the Manhattan distance so there are coordinates with repeating values of x and y.

After the search is completed I have an ArrayList of Coordinates like so:

```
[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3)]
```

What I would like the function to do is return an ArrayList with the middle elements removed so that the movement will be smoother when the path is followed.

I would like the result to be like this after optimizing it:

```
[(0,0),(0,3),(1,3),(3,3)]
```

I also can't use Java 1.8 as the robot only supports up to 1.7.

Comment: So what you basically want to do is to find any subsequence where only one of the coordinates changes. Then you can just remove all elements that are not the start or end of a subsequence. Note: There is an even better solution with `O(n)` complexity, but you might stumble over it when implementing this, anyway.

Comment: You want to keep (1, 3) in the list (but not (2, 3))?

Comment: This is going to be something with a loop (at least one) and some if statements. We are not writing the code for you, so go ahead and try. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm deliberately not wring Java code:

```
for each element of the input list
   copy it to the output list
   if there are at least 3 elements in the output list
      if the last 3 elements are collinear
      remove the middle one
```

For the collinearity test use [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38338/methods-for-showing-three-points-in-mathbbr2-are-colinear-or-not) or TFG.